# After pressing volume buttons on keyboard my react app crashes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, volume

I just found a little strange behavior - in React app I have slider that changes volume, and it works good. If I will try to use default WinOS volume slider it will also works fine. But if I press buttons to increase/decrease volume on keyboard(may be in some laptop keyboards it is combination **"Fn"+ "Arrow-Up/Arrow-Down"**) it gives me an error: *"Cannot set property 'volume' of null"*. Is it bug or I miss something important? Thanks in advance. 
codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-class-vhtw8?file=/src/index.js

Comment: because `document.getElementById(num)` doesn't select anything from the DOM. value of `num` is `ARROWUP` & there's nothing with the `id` of `ARROWUP` in the DOM. hence the error. you cannot set anything on `null`. hence, `null.value` doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you @deadcoder0904, didn't noticed `num` before. I changed code a little, and it works fine now in codesandbox. But one thing to mention, my buttons wasn't `ARROWUP/ARROWDOWN` but `AUDIOVOLUMEUP/AUDIOVOLUMEDOWN`.

Comment: weird, i copy pasted from console. i did `console.log({ num })` & it was `ARROWUP` since i pressed UP ARROW KEY. anyways it works :)